Cannot find cloud build service account for GCP
I am setting up IaC with cloud build by following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/managing-infrastructure-as-code#clean-up
I've run the following in the cloud shell:
CLOUDBUILD_SA="$(gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_ID \
    --format 'value(projectNumber)')@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
    --member serviceAccount:$CLOUDBUILD_SA --role roles/editor

However, I can't find the cloudbuild service account on my cloud build to create a trigger
Cloudbuild trigger page
Though, it does exist in the settings
Cloudbuild settings page
But if I set it as the "preferred service account", it does show up on the triggers with this error
Cloudbuild trigger page with iam issues
I've gone to https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-actas to look for answers. They seem to be for App Engine, Cloud Composer, Cloud data fusion, dataflow, and dataproc.

I also do not have it in the list. But I also have this warning yellow box

Let none and it would work.

EDIT 1
If you have created your project after June 2024, the default behavior changed. To let Cloud Build use the Cloud Build default service account, you must enforce an Organisation Policy (at the org, folder or project level, but required org admin permissions).
More detail here: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/cloud-build-service-account-updates

I am not sure what I might be doing wrong to not have that. For me, it is in red with an error saying "A service account is required" https://imgur.com/a/B3ss4DR
I've gone to the settings and checked/unchecked the "Set as preferred service account" for the cloudbuild service and tested if None would work. Both give the same error.

I edited my answer, if it's a new project, it could be normal. Select the Compute Engine default service account, or another one, or enforce the organisation policy.
